# Compare two meta-fields in a wp_query (where meta-field-A is larger than meta-field-B)

Tags: wp-query, meta-query

I have a custom post type (foobar), with two meta_fields:

- `updated_at`
- `build_ran_at`

I would like to make a single WP_query, that returns on the foobar-posts, where `updated_at` is after `build_ran_at`.
Both the fields are DateTime-fields.

---

### Solution attempt

```
$foobar_query = new WP_Query([
  'post_type' => 'foobar',
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  'posts_per_page' => 999,
  'meta_query' => [
    'relation' => 'AND',
    [
      'key' => 'updated_at',
      'value' => ...? 
      'compary' => ...?
    ],
    [
      'key' => 'build_ran_at',
      'value' => ...? 
      'compary' => ...?
    ],
  ]
]);

$returned_posts = [];
if( $foobar_query->have_posts() ):
  while( $foobar_query->have_posts() ):
    $foobar_query->the_post();
    $returned_posts[] = get_post();    
  endwhile; // while( $foobar_query->have_posts() ):
  wp_reset_query();
endif; // if( $foobar_query->have_posts() ):
```

Answer (score 2):

As of writing, there is no meta query `compare` value that can do what you're trying to do, which is basically "*where <updated_at meta> > <build_ran_at meta>*". But there are two options that you can choose from as an alternative to using the `meta_query` arg:

1. Use a raw SQL to retrieve just the IDs of the posts having the `updated_at` meta greater than the `build_ran_at` meta, and then pass the IDs to `WP_Query` via the `post__in` arg like so:

   ```php
   // Build the raw SQL.
   $query = "
       SELECT p.ID
       FROM $wpdb->posts p
           INNER JOIN $wpdb->postmeta pm ON pm.post_id = p.ID
           INNER JOIN $wpdb->postmeta pm2 ON pm2.post_id = p.ID
       WHERE p.post_type = 'foobar'
           AND p.post_status = 'publish'
           AND pm.meta_key = 'updated_at'
           AND pm2.meta_key = 'build_ran_at'
           AND pm.meta_value > pm2.meta_value
       LIMIT 999
   ";

   // Get the post IDs.
   $ids = $wpdb->get_col( $query );

   // Then use the IDs as the post__in value.
   $foobar_query = new WP_Query([
       'post_type'      => 'foobar',
       'post_status'    => 'publish',
       'posts_per_page' => 999,
       'post__in'       => $ids,
   ]);
   ```
2. Or use the [`posts_clauses` hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/posts_clauses/) to add the above two JOIN clauses and also the last three conditions in the WHERE clause.

   Example using (a closure and) a custom query arg named `_updated_at` as a flag indicating whether we should filter the posts query clauses or not, to avoid other `WP_Query` queries from being affected:

   ```php
   // Add the filter.
   add_filter( 'posts_clauses', function ( $clauses, $query ) {
       if ( '> build_ran_at' === $query->get( '_updated_at' ) ) {
           global $wpdb;

           $pm = uniqid( 'pm_' ); // unique table alias
           $clauses['join'] .= " INNER JOIN $wpdb->postmeta $pm ON {$pm}.post_id = {$wpdb->posts}.ID";

           $pm2 = uniqid( 'pm_' ); // unique table alias
           $clauses['join'] .= " INNER JOIN $wpdb->postmeta $pm2 ON {$pm2}.post_id = {$wpdb->posts}.ID";

           $clauses['where'] .= " AND ( {$pm}.meta_key = 'updated_at' AND {$pm2}.meta_key = 'build_ran_at'"
               "AND {$pm}.meta_value > {$pm2}.meta_value )";
       }

       return $clauses;
   }, 10, 2 );

   // Then use the _updated_at arg in place of meta_query.
   $foobar_query = new WP_Query([
       'post_type'      => 'foobar',
       'post_status'    => 'publish',
       'posts_per_page' => 999,
       '_updated_at'    => '> build_ran_at',
   ]);
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Do not use post meta for this kind of custom data queries. The use of meta value is very slow. You should better use a custom tables and provide custom WP_Query arguments that perfectly fit your needs.